# Is it possible to run multiple independent RSelenium browsers?

Tags: r, rselenium

It is possible to run multiple scripts with multiple R sessions, but I can't get two r-scripts involving starting RSelenium server and browser to work. Is there away to make this work?

Example: run one script involving www.bbc.co.uk and another script involving www.wsj.com at the sam time on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question: yes it is possible to do this. 
One solution is to run one server and then run different remote drivers connecting to that server.